# ¿Mostrar el selector en la tab indicada cuando pulso onBackPressed en una TabLayout?

Tags: android, onbackpressed

Tengo una `TabLayout` con 2 `tabs`, cuando pulso encima de cada tab el selector se muestra encima de la tab indicada, pero cuando pulso el botón físico de atrás el selector se queda en la tab anterior.

```
TabLayout mTabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
        mTabLayout.addTab(mTabLayout.newTab()); 
        mTabLayout.addTab(mTabLayout.newTab());


    @Override
    public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
        switch (tab.getPosition()) {
            case 0:
                HomeFragment homeFragment = new HomeFragment();
                changeFragment(homeFragment, 0);
                break;
            case 1:
                EventsFragment eventsFragment = new EventsFragment();
                changeFragment(eventsFragment, 1);
                break;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
         if(mFragmentManager.getBackStackEntryCount() > 1){
            mFragmentManager.popBackStackImmediate();

        //Como hago que el selector naranja de la tab se muestre en la tab indicada

         }
    }
```

```
<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_above="@+id/tabs"
    android:id="@+id/fragment">

</FrameLayout>

<android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
    android:id="@+id/tabs"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:tabMode="fixed"
    app:tabPaddingStart="-1dp"
    app:tabPaddingEnd="-1dp"
    app:tabGravity="fill"
    android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:background="#000000" />
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: quizas ayude a algun usuario, si muestras el codigo implicado. Saludos

Comment: Hecho, lo que intento es que al pulsar el boton hacia atrás el selector de la tab se muestre en la tab indicada.

Answer (score 1):

Tienes que guardar primeramente el indice del tab seleccionado, como ejemplo la variable `CURRENT_TAB`.

Puedes seleccionar programaticamente el tab, por ejemplo si deseas seleccionar el segundo elemento (index 1) se realizaría de esta forma teniendo la instancia del layout:

```
 @Override
 public void onBackPressed() {
   tabLayout.getTabAt(CURRENT_TAB).select();
 }
```

la otra forma es mediante el adapter seleccionar el tab que deseas :

```
ViewPagerAdapter pagerAdapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getChildFragmentManager());
viewPager.setAdapter(pagerAdapter);
viewPager.setCurrentItem(CURRENT_TAB);
```